# How can I store data, using Jsoup

Tags: java, arraylist, jsoup, store

My problem is the following: I got some data with Jsoup from a website (Jsoup code is from here also)

```
    public class Kereso {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String html = "http://www.szerencsejatek.hu/xls/otos.html";

      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();


       Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");

       Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select(":not(thead) tr");
       for (Element row : tableRowElements) {

           Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
           for (Element rowItem : rowItems) {
               System.out.println(rowItem.text());
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

Every line that I get from the website should be an object and I want to store all of these objects in an ArrayList

This is the class for the objects, and the data they need:

```
public class Huzas {

    private String ev;
    private String het;
    private String huzasdatum;
    private String otosDb;
    private String otos;
    private String negyesDb;
    private String negyes;
    private String harmasDb;
    private String harmas;
    private String kettesDb;
    private String kettes;
    private int szam1;
    private int szam2;
    private int szam3;
    private int szam4;
    private int szam5;

    public Huzas(String ev, String het, String huzasdatum, String otosDb, String otos, String negyesDb, String negyes, String harmasDb, String harmas, String kettesDb, String kettes, int szam1, int szam2, int szam3, int szam4, int szam5) {
        this.ev = ev;
        this.het = het;
        this.huzasdatum = huzasdatum;
        this.otosDb = otosDb;
        this.otos = otos;
        this.negyesDb = negyesDb;
        this.negyes = negyes;
        this.harmasDb = harmasDb;
        this.harmas = harmas;
        this.kettesDb = kettesDb;
        this.kettes = kettes;
        this.szam1 = szam1;
        this.szam2 = szam2;
        this.szam3 = szam3;
        this.szam4 = szam4;
        this.szam5 = szam5;
    }
```

Is it possible to store them in that way? And if Yes, of course how?

Comment: Is the order of each column that is on the site fixed ? Or does the ordering of the columns change ?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest the builder pattern, here, at least with a strongly typed approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that site has a simple and structured html you could simply do like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Kereso {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String html = "http://www.szerencsejatek.hu/xls/otos.html";
        List<Huzas> listOfHuzas = new ArrayList<Huzas>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
        Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
        rows.remove(0); //Remove head row
        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements children = row.children();
            listOfHuzas.add(new Huzas(children.get(0).text(), // ev
                            children.get(1).text(), // het
                            children.get(2).text(), // huzasdatum
                            children.get(3).text(), // otosDb
                            children.get(4).text(), // otos
                            children.get(5).text(), // negyesDb
                            children.get(6).text(), // negyes
                            children.get(7).text(), // harmasDb
                            children.get(8).text(), // harmas
                            children.get(9).text(), // kettesDb
                            children.get(10).text(), // kettes
                            Integer.parseInt(children.get(11).text()), // szam1
                            Integer.parseInt(children.get(12).text()), // szam2
                            Integer.parseInt(children.get(13).text()), // szam3
                            Integer.parseInt(children.get(14).text()), // szam4
                            Integer.parseInt(children.get(15).text())) // szam5
                        );
        }
        System.out.println(listOfHuzas);
    }
}
```

Since every row had exactly 16 columns and all int field had values i just directly indexed the child elements for simplicity. You may add more length checks or error handling here.

Comment: Here I only get the hashcode of the elements. How can I get the data/content of the objects?

Comment: Oh never mind. I think overriding the toString() will solve this.

Comment: Both answers works fine, but with this, the code stais more readable, and it's easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

> Every line that I get from the website should be an object and I want to store all of these objects in an ArrayList.

To link the columns data with your `Huzas` object, you will have to write a wrapper.

If I am not mistaken, you are iterating through a table on some site, so you should already have an idea as to the ordering of the columns. Simply catch the values of each coloumn on iteration and set the value of your Huzas object as it is encountered.

But first we need some list where we can map our columns with the values obtained on each DOM iterations.

```
// The elements should be in order of the columns in the DOM
String[] columnsFromDOM = {"ev", "huzasdatum", "het" ..... }
```

Now

```
List<Huzas> listOfHuzas = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element row : tableRowElements) {

       Map<String, String> columnToObjectMap = new HashMap<>();
       Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
       int index = 0;
       for (Element rowItem : rowItems) {
           // (key,value) => ("ev", value_from_dom )
           columnToObjectMap.put(columnsFromDOM[index], rowItem.text());
           indexx++;
       }

       // now columnToObjectMap contains your values along with the relavant keys
       // So now catch each value and assign it to a Huzas object

       String ev = columnToObjectMap.get("ev");
       String kettes = columnToObjectMap.get("kettes");
       ......

       Huzas huzas = new Huzas(ev, het, .....);
       listofHuzas.add(huzas);
   }
```

Comment: In this line: columnToObjectMap.put(columnsFromDOM, rowItem.text()); the IDE said: incomptaible types: String[] can not be converted to String

The other parts, works fine.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely right. A smal typeo. Updating the answer. It should be `columnsFromDOM[index]` instead of `columnsFromDOM`